# Angular UI dropdown list selection

Tags: angularjs

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/4dGT2cwdfr5ABBhQlNsw?p=preview) I have an Angular UI dropdown. Is there a way NOT to repeat the ng-click in each `<a>` element?

HTML

```
<div class="btn-group" uib-dropdown>
  <button id="btn-append-to-body" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" 
      uib-dropdown-toggle>
      {{selection}} <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" uib-dropdown-menu="" role="menu" 
        aria-labelledby="btn-append-to-body">
    <li role="menuitem">
      <a href="#" ng-click="selectItem('1')">The first item</a>
    </li>
    <li role="menuitem">
      <a href="#" ng-click="selectItem('2')">Another item</a>
    </li>
    <li role="menuitem">
      <a href="#" ng-click="selectItem('3')">Yet another item</a>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Delegate event to the UL or better create simple directive to make this delegation for you.

Comment: can you point me to an explanation of "delegate event" ?

Comment: Just normal DOM event delegation. Nothing angular specific. But it's better to create directive for this anyway (unless you use jQuery in the project, which already has it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kobd3fs63MgCnEiRkFsg?p=preview) shows how to use a global **ng-click** (passing the source `$event`) and selecting the `data-value` attribute as selected value :

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" ng-click="selectItem($event)" uib-dropdown-menu="" role="menu" aria-labelledby="btn-append-to-body">
           <li role="menuitem">
              <a href="#" data-value="1" >The first item</a>
            </li>
            <li role="menuitem">
              <a href="#" data-value="2">Another item</a>
            </li>
            <li role="menuitem">
              <a href="#" data-value="3">Yet another item</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

The `selectItem()` function , getting the data-value property of selected anchor (`ev.target`):

```
$scope.selectItem = function(ev) {
    $scope.selection = ev.target.dataset.value
};
```

Comment: Perfect, is there a way to set the label selected on the button, instead of the code?

Comment: No, it's not reliable (will not work for `<a href="#" data-value="3">Yet another item <i class="fa fa-star"></i></a>` if you click icon).

Comment: but I don't need the icon, just the label

Comment: Sure it will work for this structure. Not reliable means that it can break even if CSS changes (maring, for example). You also can't change HTML, like adding anything inside labels. If it's okay with you, then fine. Just be aware about limitations.

Comment: To set the value using the text of the link you can use $scope.selection = ev.target.textContent (http://plnkr.co/edit/7XW5eduSTreCkNLfimbC?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you can write like below with `ng-repeat`

**Controller Code:**

```
//Your controller logic
$scope.selectItems = ["First Item", "Another Item", "One More Item"]
//some more logic in your controller
```

**HTML View**

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" uib-dropdown-menu="" role="menu" aria-labelledby="btn-append-to-body" ng-repeat="(key, value) in selectItems ">
      <li role="menuitem">
        <a href="#" ng-click="selectItem('key')">{{value}}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

as I don't have access I can't able to update your plunker

Comment: No, I cannot use ng-repeat in this example. I updated the question to be clearer.

Comment: because I'm trying to keep the dropdown options in the HTML markup, not in the javascript

Comment: What do you mean by `keep the dropdown options in the HTML markup, not in the javascript`

Comment: How you will pass data from one element to another element with out using `javascript`?

Comment: I will use javascript to get the selected element, but the list of options I prefer to mantain in the HTML instead of an array in the javascript

Comment: I don't think HTML has that options, if you find that solution let me know :P

Comment: He just prefers to keep his menu items in the HTML markup.  Ain't nothing wrong with that.